# Login into app and get session token from server for api requests

Tags: android, api, authentication

There is a website with a lot of users. In order to use the private pages the user has to login with username and password.

Now I'm working on a android app that displays content from the website via an API in a native way, no WebView or similar. The workflow would be the following:

- App is started
- App checks if a sessionkey exists.

  - If the key exists, ask the website API if the sessionkey is valid and belongs to the user
    => if so, allow the usage of the app
  - If no sessionkey exists, ask for username+passwort, ask the API if it's correct and get a new sessionkey via the API => allow app usage
- User clicks on e.g. "account balance"
  -> API request is done with the stored sessionkey and the result is displayed
- User clicks on "payout", fills in a form and gets his money
  -> API request is done with the stored sessionkey and the result is displayed

Now I'm searching for a best practice solve for this. **I don't want my sessionkeys to be simply hijack-able and I want to be sure that the sessionkey realy belongs to this user**. As private data can be seen/modified via the app, privacy is important.

I took a look at oAuth but this isn't what I need I think because I need a consumer key and consumer secret that is unique for every user and I can't integrate this into the app. I don't want to have a new window/browser for entering username+password and handle the response via a callback like oAuth is doing.

Any hints on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use shardPreference for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good starting point on http authentication best practices, have a look at this article:

["Principles for Standardized REST Authentication"](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send private data, you *need to* use HTTPS. That will also take care of securing your session tokens, etc. If you need to check what token belongs to what user, you naturally need to have this mapping on the server side. Most server side platforms give you a session map or similar, keyed by session ID, etc. and you can store pretty much anything in it, including user details.

Comment: I will be using HTTPS, i forgot to mention this above. Thanks for the hints!